# Android: Llenar arraylist usando retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

Necesito llenar el arraylist con lo que me esta devolviendo retrofit en onResponse cuando hago el debug logro ver los datos pero cuando los retorno la lista esta vacia, parece que esta retornado cuando aun no se hace la llamada a la api. como podria solucionarlo?

```
  fun ListRecipe() : ArrayList<RecipeObj> {
        var obj: ArrayList<RecipeObj> = ArrayList<RecipeObj>()
        var recetas: RecipeObj?
      //  RecipeLiveData = MutableLiveData<hitsobj>()
        val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Credentials.Url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        val service: ApiService = retrofit.create<ApiService>(ApiService::class.java)
        service.getAllRecipe("rice", Credentials.App_Id, Credentials.App_Key).enqueue(object : Callback<RecipeObj> {
            override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<RecipeObj>, response: Response<RecipeObj>?) {
                 recetas = response!!.body()
                var list = listOf(recetas)
             
                obj.add(recetas!!)
               
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RecipeObj>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.message.toString())
            }
        })
        return(obj)
    }
```

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067

Comment: As the previous comment said, you need some way to handle the asynchronous approach... so with your approach always return an empty list because the call is not finished yet but you are returning the empty list value... a classic way to handle this is using a callback